# Visualization for univariate binary logistic regression with a categorical independent variable

Tags: regression, logistic, data-visualization, binary-data

I am performing a univariate logistic regression where the outcome is obviously 0 or 1, and the independent variable has 18 different levels. I am looking for a way to graph the results of this regression, but most visualizations seem to be based around the assumption that the outcome is numerical.

Are there any common visualizations for this type of model that I am somehow missing in my searching?

Comment: You could try visualising the probability in response to changes in your independent variable. Predict the probability of outcome 1 at different levels of the independent variable and plot it.

Comment: The regression yields a different probability for each level of the categorial variable. You can thus us a bar plot.

Comment: Thanks so much! I guess I'll go with a barplot - would converting the coefs to log-likelihood be the best for this type of visualization?

Answer (score 2):

With logistic regression, your response variable is 0 or 1.  If you only have 1 explanatory variable, and it is categorical, then everything is finite counts in discrete combinations.  You could just make a $2\times 18$ table.  If you want to, you could convert the table from raw counts to column-wise proportions.  If you want a visualization, you can make a stacked bar plot with 18 adjacent bars.  You might want to sort the categories: if there is a natural order, use that, otherwise increasing order, or if people will try to look up the category they're interested in, maybe alphabetical order, although this is typically less good and 18 shouldn't overwhelm people.  You don't need to worry about converting the coefficients from your model: with all categorical variables, they will exactly match the observed proportions.